# Can I access Azure private endpoint via NAT translation?

Tags: azure, networking, nat, azure-private-link

We have an Azure App Service which is accessed through a private endpoint from our on-premise environment. This works well but we have also a separate Data Center that needs access to the App Service. We have tried to do this via NAT translation:

- App Service

  - Access only trough private endpoint with ip 22.22.222.22.
  - Has custom domain: test.com
- On-premise

  - DNS has record: test.com 22.22.222.22
  - NAT translation for 11.11.111.11 > 22.22.222.22
- Data Center

  - ip 22.22.222.22 does not exist here
  - Has ip-address: test.com 11.11.111.11
  - Hosts table has record: test.com 11.11.111.11

[image: Photo of the architecture]

Unfortunatly this does not work. Could you please help me with this? Is this the right way or should we try something else?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I access Azure private endpoint via NAT translation\

- *Yes, you an access Azure private endpoint with NAT translation but for that you need to use **Source Network Address Translation**(SNAT)*
- *SNAT is the gateway which is used when your private application wants to connect with a public  host over the internet.*

[image]

- *For more information you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/nat-gateway/nat-gateway-resource#source-snat-port-reuse) document.*